# Math jax unable to convert equation with backticks to word equation

Tags: javascript, mathjax, mathml

```
`[[2 1 3], [0 3 5], [-1 2 5]]` + `[[1 -2 3], [2 6 1], [0 -3 1]]`
```

Above is the equation, when I am using mathjax 3.1.4, it gets rendered in html but the dialog to copy as MathML code is not appearing. I am using the mathjax CDN

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.1.4/es5/tex-mml-chtml.min.js

But when the equations are of the following type mathjax is able to convert them into mathML equation and the dialog to copy the equation appears.

```
\[A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ p & q & r\end{bmatrix}\]
```

For the above equation I am using the following CDN

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML

How can I convert the equation with backticks (1st equation) into mathML equation?

Answer (score 1):

The contextual dialog is working for me with the additional AsciiMath loader specified in the configuration. see: [Loading the AsciiMath Component](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/asciimath.html#loading-the-asciimath-component)

```
MathJax = {
    loader: {
        load: ['input/asciimath', 'output/chtml']
    },
};`
```

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  loader: {load: ['input/asciimath', 'output/chtml']},
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.1.4/es5/tex-mml-chtml.min.js">
</script>

<p>
`[[2 1 3], [0 3 5], [\-1 \2 5]] + [[1 -2 3], [2 6 1], [0 -3 1]]`
</p>
```